# Why is the consecutive days counter not counting days?

Tags: support

I have been trying to get to 100 consecutive days, but I seem to have a problem with it.

I am sure that I had visited SO yesterday (IST) multiple times, **on Saturday**

I just logged in at 8.30PM IST **on Sunday** and it shows that I didn't visit on Saturday. Why could this be?

I have noticed it earlier as well. Is it timezone differences causing this?